# Loading numerical data from a text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file which is

```
1.25e5  15

2.7e6   12

18.e5   14
```

I want to read the text as a 2d array and assign the first column as x and second as y.

Can anyone help me how can I do that. I did

```
f = open('energy.txt', 'r')
x = f.readlines()
```

but I don't know how to create the first column.

Comment: Do you use numpy?

Comment: yes I use numpy as np

Comment: My answer should work. If it helps, you can upvote/mark accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're okay with numpy, you can just use `np.loadtxt`:

```
In [270]: np.loadtxt('energy.txt')
Out[270]: 
array([[  1.25000000e+05,   1.50000000e+01],
       [  2.70000000e+06,   1.20000000e+01],
       [  1.80000000e+06,   1.40000000e+01]])
```

---

Alternatively, the python way to do this is:

```
In [277]: data = []

In [278]: with open('energy.txt') as f:
     ...:     for line in f:
     ...:         i, j = line.split()
     ...:         data.append([float(i), int(j)])
     ...:         

In [279]: data
Out[279]: [[125000.0, 15], [2700000.0, 12], [1800000.0, 14]]
```

With this approach, you store data as a list of lists, not a numpy array of floats. Also, you'll need to add a try-except in case you have any deviant lines in your file.

Comment: Hi man, do you think it is really bad answer? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48730792/2901002)