# Python calculate management tenure based on role database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a role database (as pd dataframe) that has the following variables: individual, company and year - with only one individual for every company-year combination.

Now, I want to create a new dataframe with every unique company as the index and calculate, how long the most recent individual has been in the company.

E.g. the **following should have an output of A,4 and B,2** in a new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Individual_ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
 'Company': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
 'Year':[2016,2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if `Individual_ID` are sorted per `Company`:

```
df = df.groupby('Company')['Individual_ID'].apply(lambda x: (x == x.iat[0]).sum())
print (df)
Company
A    4
B    2
Name: Individual_ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, jezrael! It works well for me, tested it on the dataset - since I am new here, I can't upvote yet...